# Error during initializing the Scanner of mPop Printer

Tags: eaaccessory

I am developing a point of Sale Application in which there is requirement of Bluetooth connectivity which printer and scanner. I am using star Printer. I am getting following error randomly when scanner is being initialized.

ERROR - opening session 
ERROR - /SourceCache/ExternalAccessory/ExternalAccessory-288.20.7/EASession.m:-[EASession dealloc] - 141 unable to close session for _accessory=0x16768100 and sessionID=65536

Thanks,
Ratneshwar

Answer (score 0):

I had the same bug, so finally i fixed it downloading the mPOP utility and changing in the bluetooth configuration the Name port.

It isnt a complete solution, but while star micronics fix the problem can works to the customers.

EDIT: If you have implemented both sdks StarIO.framework and StarIO_extension.framework and you are using the barcode lector always in your app you should use the method [_starIoExtManager.lock lock]; before you try to get the connection of the port and after you do that and close the port, use [_starIoExtManager.lock unlock];